# Getting Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500

Tags: javascript, c#, websocket

I am trying web socket first time. I have written following code in html. I am using ASP.NET application. VS2012 -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var ws;
            $().ready(function () {
                $("#btnConnect").click(function () {
                    $("#spanStatus").text("connecting");
                    ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost/ChatTest/WSHandler.ashx");
                    ws.onopen = function () {
                        $("#spanStatus").text("connected");
                    };
                    ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
                        $("#spanStatus").text(evt.data);
                    };
                    ws.onerror = function (evt) {
                        $("#spanStatus").text(evt.message);
                    };
                    ws.onclose = function () {
                        $("#spanStatus").text("disconnected");
                    };
                });
  </script>
```

This code is giving error - "WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/ChatTest/WSHandler.ashx' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500"

I have enbled WebSocket Protocol from Web Server -> Application Development -> WebSocket Protocol. I am using Windowa server 2012 R2 and IIS 8.5.

Comment: The fact you are getting an HTTP 500 means there is an unhandled exception happening in your code at the server level. Check the logs if you have any or just run the app in debug and try to see what is going on.